# C++11: Body of class initialization assignment order

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Say I have a class of the form

```
class MyClass
{
    int a = 1;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d = 4;
    MyClass() : b(2)
    {
        c = 3;
    }
}
```

What is the order of the assignment of `a,b,c,d`? Now I know for sure (from older C++) that `b` will be assigned before `c`. But what about the others with respect to the latter?

Comment: All non-static data members are initialized in declaration order, regardless of if they have a brace-or-equal initializer. The compound-statement of the constructor body is performing assignment, which is orthogonal to initialization. All non-static data members were initialized before its execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [class.base.init]:

> non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).

In this case, the ordering would be equivalent to:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c;
int d = 4;
c = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks. Honestly I find this hard to believe. How could `a` beat `b` if `b` beats `d`?  Could you please provide a reference?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Why's it "hard to believe", and what's this about variables "beating" each other?? The variables are initialised with the initialisers you gave them, if any, in declaration order. That's it. It's really quite straightforward.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Beat is used in English to state that something preceded something else. Sorry if that's not clear. It's hard to believe because they don't follow any logical order.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: I probably know more about the English language than you do, and your use of the term here is really quite peculiar. What is not "logical"? It's declaration order. That's it. Simply declaration order. Why is that not "logical"? It's precisely how it would work in, say, a function.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I gave you the reference from the C++ standard. They're in initialized in the order of declaration - in this case, in alphabetical order. The initialization is performed by the *mem-initializers* (for `b`) or the *brace-or-equal-initializers* (for `a` and `d`) or none (for `c`)

Comment: They follow a very logical order -- the order they were declared in the class! In your class definition, `a` comes first, then `b`, then `c`, then `d`. So that is the order in which they are initialized, regardless of whether some of the member variables show up in the constructor's initializer list.